# Кодирование файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha256

Возникает ошибка при кодировании текста из файлов, я так понял что просто закодировать строку с помощью sha256 нельзя. Возникает ошибка при запуске.
Код:

```
import hashlib
import tkinter as tk
def show_text():
    my_file = open(road.get(),'r')
    my_string = my_file.read()
    sha = hashlib.sha256(my_string).hexdigest()
    my_file1.close()
    my_file1 = open(road.get1(),'r')
    my_string1 = my_file1.read()
    sha1 = hashlib.sha256(my_string1).hexdigest()
    my_file1.close()
    if sha == sha1:
        label_text2.set("Файлы одинаковые")
    else:
        label_text2.set("Файлы разные")
    result="" + label_text2.get() + "\n" + sha + " - 1  файл \n"+sha1+" - 2 файл"
    handle = open(road2.get(), "w")
    handle.write(result)
    handle.close()
root = tk.Tk()

road = tk.StringVar()
road1 = tk.StringVar()
road2 = tk.StringVar()
label_text = tk.StringVar()
label_text1 = tk.StringVar()
label_text2 = tk.StringVar()
label_text3 = tk.StringVar()
label_text4 = tk.StringVar()
label_text5 = tk.StringVar()
label_text5.set("Введите путь ко второму файлу")
label3 = tk.Label(root, textvariable="Введите путь к первому файлу")
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=road)
entry.pack()
label4 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text5)
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=road1)
entry.pack()
label5 = tk.Label(root, textvariable="Введите путь к файлу в который сохранить результат")
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=road2)
entry.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=show_text)
button.pack()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text)
label1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text1)
label2 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text2)
label.pack()
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
label3.pack()
label4.pack()
label5.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\8440p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, i
n __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Python\pyth1.py", line 6, in show_text
    sha = hashlib.sha256(my_string).hexdigest()
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Comment: Открывайте файл для чтения в бинарном режиме (режим `'rb'`), тогда заработает.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, заработало, оставьте ответ я приму

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `sha256` работает с байтами, а не со строками. Чтобы прочитать файл в виде байт, его нужно открывать в бинарном режиме (`'rb'` вместо `'r'`):

```
my_file = open(road.get(),'rb')
my_string = my_file.read()
```